# jQuery Mobile interactive link with title and description MVC

Tags: jquery-mobile, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to have an interactive list element with a title and description.

I have an action link and a p tag.

```
 <li>@Html.ActionLink((string)Model.Date.ToShortDateString(), "Details", new { id = Model.id})
  <p style="padding-left: 15px;">@Model.RecordType</p>
 </li>
```

Is it possible to also make the description 'clickable'? The title is in the correct place, but if the user were to touch the description on accident, it would not trigger the action link.

This li is enclosed in a `<ul data-role="listview">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was when I was testing it in a browser. When testing on a mobile device, this problem does not exist.